# Android Translate/Slide up part of Linear Layout to show other views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

The layout structure can be seen here[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4X6P.jpg)

I am trying to translate the Linear layout, so that the Horizontal scrollview becomes visible.The FancyCoverflow fills the entire screen at first, due to Height and width set as match_parent:
My current code is as shown

```
linearLayout.animate().translationY(-200).setDuration(500);
```

However, the linearLayout gets translated up, but the Horizontal scrollview is never translated or visible.

Instead, I just get an empty space at the bottom of the screen after the translation.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, It may help you.

**UPDATE** Write a demo:

I don't have a HorizontalListView here, so I write this demo for vertical ListView

***First***, create your layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Click"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragInvi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:background="#253">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_test"
        android:background="#253"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

***Second:*** write some code:

```
final FrameLayout fragInvi = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragInvi);

ListView lv_test = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_test);
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0;i < 10; i++){arr.add("String "+i);}
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
lv_test.setAdapter(adapter);
lv_test.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Click on "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

final boolean[] isTranslated = {false};

Button btn_Click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Click);
btn_Click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!isTranslated[0]){
            fragInvi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fragInvi.animate().translationY(-fragInvi.getHeight()).setDuration(500);
        }else{
            fragInvi.animate().translationY(fragInvi.getHeight()).setDuration(500);
        }
            isTranslated[0] = !isTranslated[0];

        }
    });
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: This is my solution, not a recommend or a requirement to get more information of question.

Comment: FrameLayout stacks its children. I want the Horizontal scrollview to appear /slide up from the bottom.

Comment: Wrap your LinearLayout inside FrameLayout and translate FrameLayout

Comment: Still the same empty space as before.

Comment: Try to use relative layout. It adjusts views according to available space when keyboard is shown

Comment: wrap HorizontalListView inside FrameLayout, instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: @vandaics I tried your implementation. It works fine for the Horizontal Listview, However I also want the visible view to scroll up i.e the FancyCoverflow in my diagram/ the RelativeLayout in your code.

Comment: @vandaics Your answer doesnt solve my problem. The questions reads "Translate/Slide up Part of Linear Layout"

Comment: you don't know that only FrameLayout can translate without affect on all other views inside it. So, If you want to translate LinearLayout/RelativeLayout and get exactly event on view inside them, just ask google inc to build other OS.

Comment: @vandaics At least be nice..It will help you in life in anything you do.